# How to make a div scroll over carousel Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Say I have a carousel and a container right under it. How do i make the container scroll ontop of the carousel? Sort of like a parallax effect I guess.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">     
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p>123</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">    
          <p>456</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <p>789</p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

something like in this site http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-promo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this codepen idea : http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie

You will set it up like that :

```
<div class="box" data-scroll-speed="2">S</div>
```

The highest data-scroll-speed is, the slowest it will scroll.

You'll require jQuery, but the result would be something like that :
https://jsfiddle.net/mk0hdtsj/2